# Chai logs error into console instead of failing the test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chai

I have the following test code that verifies that after calling a function that returns a promise, the resulting array is the same as the stubbed one.

```
it('Should return locations', () => {
  const result = loginSvc.getLocations()

  expect(result).to.eventually.eql(['location1', 'asd', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5'])   
})
```

`loginSvc.getLocations()` is just a function that is mocked and returns an array: `['location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5']`

When I run the test it doesn't fail as it should or even succeed as a false positive, and in the console I get this:

> ERROR LOG: 'Unhandled promise rejection', AssertionError{message: 'expected [ Array(5) ] to have the same members as [ Array(5) ]', showDiff: true, actual: ['location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5'], expected: ['location1', 'asd', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5'], stack: 'AssertionError@http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:9320:24
>   assert@http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:239:31
>   somethingMethod@http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai-things/lib/chai-things.js?da5f13ef7d7d30f512b1cd8c3a12b3ed43cd7d31:97:30
>   overwritingMethodWrapper@http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:8932:38
>   allMethod@http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai-things/lib/chai-things.js?da5f13ef7d7d30f512b1cd8c3a12b3ed43cd7d31:165:30
>   overwritingMethodWrapper@http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:8932:38
>   http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:3379:16
>   methodWrapper@http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:7709:30
>   http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js?ac71de40b7ca85a0488f7d3c971a22ddd0e149a8:308:31
>   run@http://localhost:9000/base/spec.js?20bf9e1ddf32e8fc2bfe38226be11b7e65336abf:72447:29
>   http://localhost:9000/base/spec.js?20bf9e1ddf32e8fc2bfe38226be11b7e65336abf:72460:33
>   flush@http://localhost:9000/base/spec.js?20bf9e1ddf32e8fc2bfe38226be11b7e65336abf:72685:11', line: 243, sourceURL: 'http://localhost:9000/base/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae'}

But the test passes

Comment: Please, provide all relevant code. There's no loginSvc.getLocations. It remains unclear how comes that AngularJS service uses native promise. The question doesn't even mention which testing framework is used (Chai is framework-agnostic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found a solution, or rather a workaround:

```
it('Should return locations', done => {
  loginSvc.getLocations()
    .then(locations => {
      expect(locations ).to.eql(['location1', 'asd', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5'])
      done()
    })
    .catch(done)
})
```